# How to draw image in canvas compose without stretching the image

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am using canvas composable to draw an image bitmap and get the result like this

[image]

This is my code to draw the image and the image source is a landscape image

```
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), onDraw = {
        drawImage(imageBitmap, dstSize = IntSize(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt()),)
    })
```

Is there any way to keep the image not stretching while drawing it in canvas? Really appreciate any suggestions

--- Update ---

This is the result I expect

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do? Fit to the canvas and maintain aspect ratio?

Comment: Yup, I want the image display fit and keep it ratio (as ContentScale.Fit in image composable). You can see the result I expect in my question (I have added the expected result in my question). Is there any suggestion? @Philio